# How can I expand my video.js player on facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, video, video.js

My idea is, when you pasted a link from my blog to the facebook wall, you can play it, just like youtube player.
I have video.js, and I tryed this tags:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://zobolio.com/embeds/video-js.swf?video=http://zobolio.com/embeds/test.flv" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://zobolio.com/embeds/video-js.swf?video=https://zobolio.com/embeds/test.flv" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

But not working, and I would like to know why?
And I would like to also know how can this work?
[Here](http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/embeds/ezekiel.html) a example with video.js player.
**Edit:**
I added a fully flash player and a FLV file and https, and also dosen't work.

Comment: I need to do the same thing. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Well I better Know now, as I stared.
Unfortunetly, facebook ask https protocol for embed anything.
If you don't whant pay, that's okey, I Found this:
https://www.startssl.com/
The problem with it not realy safe, and very complicate activate, becouse need a subdomain from site list, so you can't add your owen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is:
The video.js dosen't work with facebook.
Yeah, it has swf file, but just for fallback.
The solution is:
Must be switch player to JW 5.1 pro, and must be give some necessery og meta tags, which I never saw before.
Here the tags:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
<meta property="og:type"        content="video.movie" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="420" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Big Buck Bunny" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation." />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100000446876505">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="257720611082074">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://zobolio.com/embeds/posters/ezekiel.png" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://zobolio.com/embeds/jwplayer5/player.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zobolio.com/embeds/ezekiel.mp4&autostart=true" /> 
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://zobolio.com/embeds/jwplayer5/player.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zobolio.com/embeds/ezekiel.mp4&autostart=true" />
```

Of course, if you have your own player, you must chancge content section to your datas.

Answer (score 1):

This only works with a Flash player, not with video.js or any other HTML5 player. You need to provide a path to a swf along with whatever parameters are needed to load a particular video. You are also required to give an https URL to the player as `og:video:secure_url`.

So something like:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/path/to/player.swf?video=http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/embeds/ezekiel.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://example.com/path/to/player.swf?video=https://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/embeds/ezekiel.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

You may find some older examples with a URL to an MP4 file in `og:video` and `video/mp4` for `og:video:type`, but this doesn't workany more if it ever did.

Comment: Well, video.js is has swf file which name is: video-js.swf.
You think this can work with, or just search a fully flashplayer, like follow player?

Comment: Now, The player is flash, file is FLV, and I have https, but dosen't work

Comment: No, video.js's swf for Flash fullback wouldn't work. It's not a standalone player.

Comment: Yeah thanks your answer, but I solved this, you can read my answer in the top

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the parameters of file video-js.swf

See:

http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.swf?src=http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4&autoplay=true&preload=none&poster=http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.swf?src=http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4&autoplay=true&preload=none&poster=http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.swf?src=http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4&autoplay=true&preload=none&poster=http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```